# What is a better way to store status updates in a database?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm developing a web application that will enable users to post short status updates similar to Twitter. The only way I can think of storing these posts is to have a large "status_updates" table that stores EVERY user's status updates:

```
--------------------------------------
| table: status_updates              |
-------------------------------------|
| id | user_who_posted | update_text |
--------------------------------------
```

This method requires something like this SQL query to get each user's updates:

```
SELECT * FROM status_updates where user_who_posted="username"
```

and I think that wouldn't be very inefficient. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want a datetime or timestamp column in that table, too: I can't imagine a variant of the app you describe where it would be irrelevant WHEN a status update was posted!

Comment: You're correct, I simplified the table for the purpose of creating a more clear question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a user table, and have the `user_id` be an integer foreign key to that user table.  Then, build an index on the `user_id` field to allow for rapid retrieval.

In short:

```
status_updates:
--------------------------------------
|  status_id  |  user_id  |  status  |
--------------------------------------
|          1  |        1  |  Woot!   |
--------------------------------------
|          2  |        1  |  Yeah!   |
--------------------------------------
|          3  |        2  |  Hello!  |
--------------------------------------

users:
--------------------------
|  user_id  |  username  |
--------------------------
|        1  |  'Joe'     |
--------------------------
|        2  |  'John'    |
--------------------------
```

Then, to retrieve, you would do this:

```
select
    u.username,
    s.status
from
    status_updates s
    inner join users u on
        s.user_id = u.user_id
where
    u.username = 'John'
```

This will retrieve:

```
-------------------------
|  username  |  status  |
-------------------------
|  John      |  Hello!  |
-------------------------
```

Do with that what you will.  That will be very performant on millions of rows, so long as you build your indexes right.  What RDBMS are you using, so I can point you to the right spot for that?

Answer (score 1):

This actually can be very efficient as long as you properly set up an index for the status_updates table on user.

If you are truly worried about the table becoming very, very large you may want to look into [horizontal partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)) of your database(s).

Answer (score 1):

It would be quicker to not have a string as part of your search criteria, and instead have your user replaced with a surrogate key:

```
SELECT update_text
FROM status_updates
INNER JOIN users
    ON status_updates.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.username = 'username'
```

Obviously, indexing and potentially partitioning your table could be useful for scalability.